# Python: Converting an xarray.Dataset to netcdf - process killed

Tags: python, bigdata, netcdf, python-xarray, catalog

From a cluster I have an `xarray.DataArray` with precipitation data.

I got a message: `Killed`.

This is what I did in a nutshell (after checking @Michael Delgado comment)

```
import intake
import xarray as xr 
import pandas as pd


# getting catalog
catalog_file = "/my/path/catalog.json"

cat = intake.open_esm_datastore(catalog_file)
pre_catalog = cat.search( variable_id="pr", frequency="30minutes")

# Loading data
dataset_dict = pre_catalog.to_dataset_dict(cdf_kwargs={"chunks": {"time": 1}})

# getting Array
for name, data_set in data_dict.items():
    pass

data_set["pr"]
```

[image: This is my precipitation xarray]

```
# trying to save data as netcdf
data["pr"].to_netcdf("/my/path/pre_30min_test.nc")
```

Can anyone point me out in the right direction?
How can I convert an `xarray.DataArray` to a `netcdf` file in this case without getting any `killed` prompt?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: we need to see all your code to help with this. it's not the writing to netCDF that is the problem. the issue is likely that you are lazy-loading your data (e.g. xr.open_dataset) and the data is too large, but has not been loaded until you trigger it with a write. you could likely fix the problem by using dask, such as by chunking the array on read with e.g. `xr.open_dataset(fp, chunks={"lat": 100, "lon": 100})` or something along these lines. see examples in the [xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/dask.html) and [dask](https://examples.dask.org/xarray.html) docs

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you for the support. I tried `dataset_dict = pre_catalog.to_dataset_dict(cdf_kwargs={"chunks": {"time": 1}})` now I am waiting to see if it works, seems that it still not easy to compute. Maybe I should chunk it more? And I guess I will get a chunked netcdf file. Is there a way to "merge" them all in the end?

Comment: “Not easy” - it’s it getting killed or just taking a long time? And no you won’t have to combine them in the netcdf - you can read it as normal. The write will go faster if you use zarr, which supports parallel writing and reading to different chunks unlike netcdf.